# SQL query to find all tables in a database that have a column with a specific name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What query can I run on a database that will tell me which tables in that database have a column named "RCPTNMBR"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most databases support this:

```
SELECT 
    table_name 
FROM 
    information_schema.columns 
WHERE
    column_name = 'x'
```

Comment: Going to mark this as the answer (as soon as SO will let me mark it) as it returned an extra table that the other answer didn't...

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
SELECT t.name as TableName, c.name as ColumnName
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.name = 'RCPTNMBR'
```